# C# ChromeDriver constructor hangs if there is another chrome instance with specific profile

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

When there is a chrome session left from previous launch for example. ChromeDriver refuses to create instance.

Code reproducing the problem:

```
var co = new ChromeOptions();
var dir = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "profile");
co.AddArgument($"user-data-dir={dir}");
var driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
var driver2 = new ChromeDriver(co);   // <-- timeout after 60 s here.
```

Is it normal in 2k18? Really?

Comment: What makes you think that it's possible to have two instances of Chrome launched on the same profile location?

Comment: I can normally launch two chrome instances. As i understand the goal of automation software is to automate tasks, and not to bring limitations from 2008. Sorry I'm upset of what selenium is.

Comment: I bet everyone who set 'user-data-dir' and not disposing driver come across this issue. When you debug you're launching program multiple times and if there will be not closed chrome window from previous launch it will hang. This is not a rocket science, just hello world not working without a workaround, sad. ((